# backbonejs's set method could not work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, set, backbone-events

I have already define a model use backbone:

```
window.ResourceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        default:{
            'relativeurl':'unknow',
            'type': "unkonw"
        },

        initialize: function(){

            this.bind("change:relativeurl", function () {
                console.log('change!',this.relativeurl);
            });

            this.bind("change:type", function () {

            });
        },

        setRelativeURL: function (url) {
             console.log('pass in',url);//this have value
             this.set({"relativeurl": url});//this's value is undefined!
        },

        delResource: function () {
            console.log("this.url",this.relativeurl);
            resourceMasterView.delResourceItem(this.url);
        }
    });
```

Then I want invoke this method

```
window.resourceModel = new ResourceModel();
resourceModel.setRelativeURL(url);
resourceModel.setType(type);
```

but just I comment above,even I already invoke the set method ,the "relativeurl" result is still undefined!

What's wrong with my code?How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the `relativeurl` attribute of a Backbone model, you say [`m.get('relativeurl')`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get); the attribute is not stored as a property of the model so this:

```
console.log('change!', this.relativeurl);
```

will always yield `undefined` for `this.relativeurl`. You should say:

```
console.log('change!', this.get('relativeurl'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/VBQ5h/

You could also access the attribute directly through [`this.attributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes) but you should usually leave `attributes` alone:

```
console.log('change!', this.attributes.relativeurl);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/y3Q6b/

Your real problem is probably confusion between *object properties* and *Backbone attributes*. Properties are fields of the object and are accessed as `o.some_property` or `o['some_property']`. Backbone models deal primarily with attributes which are stored in the model's [`attributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes) property and are accessed through [`get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) and modified through [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) (and of course [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch), [`unset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-unset), and [`clear`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clear)). Backbone models don't know anything about arbitrary object properties.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that Backbone's get/set doesn't get/set "properties" on a model object - it gets/stores "attributes" in a model object. I know it's silly and almost nit-picky, but properties always seem to be "object.someProperty", and backbone's documentation refers to them as a getter/setter for "attributes".

Comment: @Stephen: There's nothing wrong with being picky about terminology. Is the updated version better? (I'm not being snarky, I really do care about clarity :)